# Аналог setw в arduino ide

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка, arduino

Написал программу для сортировки строки по возрастанию значений сумм их элементов на с++, потом же понадобилось сделать тоже самое задание, но уже для прошивки ардуино.Вроде адаптировал код для arduino ide? но не знаю, как заменить команду `setw`. Помогите,пожалуйста.Полный код приведу под спойлером.

```
#include <Keypad.h> // подключаем нашу библиотеку
const byte ROWS = 4; //число строк у нашей клавиатуры
const byte COLS = 4; //число столбцов у нашей клавиатуры
double a[10][11];
    int n, m;
char hexaKeys[ROWS][COLS] = {
{'1','4','7','*'}, // здесь мы располагаем названия наших клавиш, как на клавиатуре,для удобства пользования
{'2','5','8','0'},
{'3','6','9','#'},
{'A','B','C','D'}

};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {7, 6, 5, 4}; //к каким выводам подключаем управление строками
byte colPins[COLS] = {11, 10, 9, 8}; //к каким выводам подключаем управление столбцами

Keypad customKeypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(hexaKeys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);
void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);
  char customKey = customKeypad.getKey();
  
  do
    {
       Serial.println("Введите количество строк от 2 до 10 n=");
        customKey = n;
    } while (n < 2 || n > 10);
    do
    {
       Serial.println("Введите количество столбцов от 2 до 10 m=");
        customKey = m;
    } while (m < 2 || m > 10);
    // Инициализируем
    
    Serial.println("Исходная матрица");
    Serial.println(setw(m*6+10) << "Сумма ")
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        a[i][m] = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = rand() / static_cast<double>(RAND_MAX) * 18 - 9;
           Serial.println(setw(6) << a[i][j]);
            a[i][m] += a[i][j];
        }
        Serial.println(setw(8) << a[i][m]);
    }
    // Сортируем
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            if (a[i][m] > a[j][m])
                for (int k = 0; k <= m; k++)
                {
                    double x = a[i][k];
                    a[i][k] = a[j][k];
                    a[j][k] = x;
                }
    // Выводим
    Serial.println("Строки упорядочены по возрастанию сумм");
    Serial.println(setw(m*6+10) << "Сумма ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            Serial.print(setw(6) << a[i][j]);
        Serial.println(setw(8) << a[i][m]);
    }
}
  
void loop(){
char customKey = customKeypad.getKey();

}
```

Comment: Зависит от того, как вы организуете ввод данных в arduino.

Comment: Забыл написать, что ввод через Serial производится

Comment: Тогда заменяйте все cin/cout на взаимодействие через Serial

Comment: Простая замена не подошла(скрыл под спойлер),т.к. нет некоторых библиотек и arduino ide ругается на синтаксис

Comment: Вроде есть не только стандартная Arduino Ide, но и другие способы, возможно ли прошить как Stm32? Может покопать в эту сторону, имхо

Comment: Действительно, есть способы. Но надо именно через arduino ide сделать замену.